# Проверка сетевого интерфейса в Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список сетевых интерфейсов, необходимо проверить каждый из них на то, является ли он активным. Пробовал проверять, установлен ли у интерфейса IP адрес, но как выяснил через гугление, установленный IP не гарантирует мне того, что интерфейс будет активен. Каким образом можно проверить на это на 100% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [102]: import wmi

In [103]: c = wmi.WMI()

In [104]: qry = "select Name from Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetEnabled=True and NetConnectionStatus=2"

In [105]: [o.Name for o in c.query(qry)]
Out[105]:
['Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller',
 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1',
 'VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8',
 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что нужно!

Comment: @TimurYalimov, пожалуйста :)